# x-editable data-source id as string

Tags: x-editable

I'm trying to use x-editable on my application.
I use data-source and set it like:

```
[{"id": django_filter_list, "text": "Django Filter List"},{"id": mixitup, "text": "MixItUp"}]
```

Problem is, id's are not integer id values, it does not working.

if I change it to

```
[{"id": 1, "text": "Django Filter List"},{"id": 2, "text": "MixItUp"}]
```

it works.

If I'm storing this choices as string values, why x-editable limits me with this, any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using your id same as your text value, i.e.,
Try using your string in the following format,
It worked for me

```
[{id: "Django Filter List", text: "Django Filter List"},{id: "MixItUp", text: "MixItUp"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use string values you have to quote them.

Try:

```
[{"id": "django_filter_list", "text": "Django Filter List"},{"id": "mixitup", "text": "MixItUp"}]
```

instead of:

```
[{"id": django_filter_list, "text": "Django Filter List"},{"id": mixitup, "text": "MixItUp"}]
```